# upgrade magento 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 give zendframework/zend-stdlib error

Tags: magento2.3, zend-framework, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.3

**upgrade Magento 2.3.2 to 2.3.3  give zendframework/zend-stdlib error.**

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>   Problem 1
>    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^3.2.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1, 3.3.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^3.2.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1, 3.3.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.3].
>   Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

**composer require zendframework/zend-stdlib ^3.2.1**

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
>       - magento/framework 102.0.2 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.7.x-dev]
>   but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - magento/framework 102.0.2 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.7.x-dev]
>   but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - magento/framework 102.0.2 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.7.x-dev]
>   but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - magento/framework 102.0.2 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.7.x-dev]
>   but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - Installation request for magento/framework 102.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.2].

Installation failed, reverting `./composer.json` to its original content.

`PHP version: 7.2.20`

Comment: What is you PHP version ?

Answer (score 1):

This message looks like one additional component depends on magento/framework 102.0.2 as the newest version, which is from Magento 2.3.2. But I suppose the error message is still not complete?